# Sum of Lagrange basis polynomials

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Let $L_i(x)$ be Lagrange basis polynomials for $n+1$ points $(x_0,y_0),\ldots, (x_n,y_n)$. How do you prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)^pL_i(x)=0$ for $p\leq n$?

Comment: $p=0$ must be excluded since $\sum L_j=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the interpolation property of the functions $L_j$. For any polynomial $f$ of degree at most $n$ the equality

$$f = \sum_{j=0}^nf(x_j)L_j$$

holds.  Apply this to $f(x,y)=(y-x)^p$. For any fixed $y$ this is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $p\leq n$ and interpolation gives

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^nf(x_j,y)L_j(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n(y-x_j)^pL_j(x).$$

If $0<p\leq n$ then $f(x,x)=0$ and the result follows.  For $p=0$ we have $f(x,x)=1$ and the interpolation above becomes

$$1=\sum_{j=0}^nL_j$$

as was already noted in the comment.